# What is the name of the HTML functionality that passes automatic arguments to javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html

In this HTML the object `event` is being passed to the function and is being used in the target javascript function  :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onclick="myFunction(event)">

  <p>Click on a paragraph. An alert box will alert the element that triggered the event.</p>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The target property returns the element that triggered the event, and not necessarily the eventlistener's element.
  </p>

  <script>
    function myFunction(event) {
      alert(event.target.nodeName);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_target)

Now should the name of the passed argument `event` be changed in the HTML, for instance into `<body onclick="myFunction(e)">`, the script wouldn't work anymore, proving that the HTML has a list of default objects ready to be fed into the javascript function calls. Do we know about the list of those defaultly named objects and how they are described in the documentation ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML, this is a JavaScript object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: No, it's not the global variable. It's a parameter to the hidden function created for `onXXX` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event` and `this`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

> When the event handler is specified as an HTML attribute, the specified code is wrapped into a function with the following parameters:
>
> - `event` — for all event handlers except `onerror`.
> - `event`, `source`, `lineno`, `colno`, and `error` for the `onerror` event handler. Note that the event parameter actually contains the error message as a string.
>
> When the event handler is invoked, the `this` keyword inside the handler is set to the DOM element on which the handler is registered. For more details, see [the this keyword documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_inline_event_handler).

Comment: Actually they are right, from your document `When the element is built from the HTML, the value of its onevent attributes are copied to the DOM object that represents the element, so that accessing the attributes' values using JavaScript will get the value set in the HTML.` So if I set a variable `a=2` in the javascript and set `<body onclick="myFunction(a)">` it will alert 2

Comment: That's something else. It means that when you have `<div id="foo" onclick="xxx">` you can then use `document.getElementById("foo").onclick` to access that attribute.

Comment: Your question was about the variables that are provided by default. But you can also access any other global variables.

Comment: `event` and `this` are not standard global variables (IE has `window.event` and Chrome copied it, but Firefox didn't).

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the `onClick` attribute. The recommended way of handling events in by doing it all in JS. You can do this by adding an event listener to the object. [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector("#myId").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.info(event.target.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<button id="myId">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't remotely answer the question that was posed.

Comment: Yes, it does. His `event.target.nodeName` was returning `null` because HTML never passed the event variable to the function, and I fixed that problem for him.

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: Yes, it was "Do we know about the list of those default named objects and how they are described in the documentation?" However, he asked that because he was trying to figure out the name of the variable to pass to his function `myFunction` from the `onclick` attribute in order to pass the event and not a null variable

Comment: The question is asking if there are other variables that are available by default inside the `onclick` attribute like `event` is.

Comment: Has anyone told him "no" then?